# Numpy custom moving window count cells in range

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have a 2d numpy array from which I want to know the count of all pixels that fall between two values specified in two stacked kernels. The borders should be excluded from the count.

For example:

```
input = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 2, 1],
   [0, 2, 1, 1, 7],
   [2, 0, 6, 4, 1],
   [1, 2, 3, 0, 5],
   [6, 5, 4, 3, 2]])

kernel_min=np.array([[0, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 2],
   [0, 0, 1]])

kernel_max=np.array([[2, 3, 2],
   [2, 2, 4],
   [2, 2, 3]])

min_max = np.dstack((kernel_min,kernel_max))

outcome= [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 7, 7, 9, 0],
   [0, 8, 8, 8, 0],
   [0, 8, 8, 8, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

To do this I created a script that loops through all elements in the input array. Around each element an area the size of the kernel is extracted and the cells within the range of the kernels are counted.

```
def create_heatmap(input,min_max):
  input_selection=np.zeros(shape(min_max ),dtype='f')
  heatmap = np.zeros(shape(input),dtype='uint16')
  length,width=shape(input)
  center=shape(min_max )[0]/2
  #exclude edge pixels
  for i in range(0+center,length-center):
    for j in range(0+center,width-center):
      # Mask area the size of the kernel around the selected cell
      input_selection= input[i-center:i+center+1,j-center:j+center+1]
      # Count the number of cells within kernel range:
      heatmap[i,j]= shape(np.where((input_selection>=min_max [:,:,0]) & (input_selection<=min_max [:,:,1])))[1]
  return heatmap`
```

This looping through all elements is however quite time consuming (I have a huge array). Is there a way to speed up the count of the pixels in the range of two kernels? For example, a moving window function which counts all values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without Python loops by using array stride tricks. The easy way is to use a readymade function, e.g. [`view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) from Scikit Image or [`extract_patches`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.17.X/sklearn/feature_extraction/image.py#L242:L297) from Scikit Learn.

```
from skimage.util import view_as_windows

def with_strides(img, kernel_min, kernel_max):
    win_w, win_h = kernel_min.shape
    heatmap = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype='uint16')
    target = heatmap[win_h//2:-win_h//2+1, win_w//2:-win_w//2+1]

    windowed = view_as_windows(img, (win_h, win_w))
    mask = ((kernel_min <= windowed) & (windowed <= kernel_max))
    np.sum(mask, axis=(2,3), out=target)

    return heatmap
```

This method is quite demanding in terms of memory however.

An alternative approach is to still use Python loops, but loop over the kernel instead of the image. The idea is to reduce overhead by calling Numpy functions on larger arrays.

```
def kernel_loops(img, kernel_min, kernel_max):
    img_h, img_w = img.shape
    win_h, win_w = kernel_min.shape
    heatmap = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype='uint16')
    target = heatmap[win_h//2:-win_h//2+1, win_w//2:-win_w//2+1]

    for i in range(win_h):
        for j in range(win_w):
            # Negative index fails when slicing to the end
            source = img[i:i+img_h-win_h+1, j:j+img_w-win_w+1]
            target += (kernel_min[i,j] <= source) & (source <= kernel_max[i,j])

    return heatmap
```

I can't provide representative timings at this moment, but the speedups should be significant. It would be interesting to see the effect of window size on performance.

Comment: This was really hepful. To test the speedups I used an 8-bit image of 1035*1400 pixels.

-With my script the calculation took about 100 seconds
-With the view_as_windows function it took about 20 seconds
-With the second approach it took about 17 seconds

This will save a lot of time when I am processing larger images. Thanks a lot!

Comment: When I increase the kernel (from 50 to 70) size and use the same image:

- with_strides = 56 sec (and a full memmory)
- kernel_loops = 32 sec

seems like the second method is more optimal!